# How wide (data + parity) would you go for erasure coded pools / raid 6?

Tags: raid, ceph

I am currently doing k=8 and m=2

or in other words data = 8 + parity = 2 shards

I am using an all hdd ceph cluster.

I have thought about going data = 11 + parity = 2 which would save a lot of data.

Theoretically, you can keep on going up but what would you suggest is a good balance for the purposes of storing data such as images (200kb-1mb in size) + smaller thumnails of 30-50kb and icons of around 10kb.

What block size would you go for?